# How can I get mutt to automatically select pgp keys?

Tags: mutt, gpg

## Problem

I wish encrypt an email to `foo@bar.com`, using `mutt`. I have an associated key, which I trust marginally. After attempting to send the email, I have to select from a list of keys, both of which appear identical.

```
->    1 ?  4096/0x123456789ABCDE01 RSA  es
      2 ?  4096/0x123456789ABCDE01 RSA  es Foo <foo@bar.com>
```

After selecting either, I am given the prompt:

```
ID has undefined validity. Do you really want to use the key? ([no]/yes):
```

Is there a way to skip these two additional steps? (Also, why are there two identical options?)

## Troubleshooting

#### Trust

If I change the trust settings of the key to "full", I still have the same issue. However, if I change it to "ultimate" then I can skip both prompts.

#### pgp-hook

Alternatively, I attempted to put the following in `~/.mutt/muttrc`.

```
pgp-hook foo@bar.com 0x123456789ABCDE01
```

Now when I attempt to send the email, it's better, but I'm still given one prompt:

```
Use keyID = "0x123456789ABCDE01" for foo@bar.com? ([yes]/no):
```

Comment: BTW, my `muttrc(5)` man page makes no mention of a `pgp-hook` command.  What version of `mutt` are you running?  mine is `1.6.0-1` from debian sid.

Comment: My knowledge of GPG is even worse, it seems. Specifically, how would I formulate those send-hook? Regarding `pgp-hook`: that's odd, `man 5 muttrc` also makes no mention of it for me either, but obviously it's having some effect. I'm using mutt 1.6.1 with the [neomutt](http://www.neomutt.org/) patches applied.

Comment: actually, some googling found an old patch for mutt 1.5.6 called [confirm-crypt-hook](http://www.woolridge.ca/mutt/confirm-crypt-hook.html).  Further googling found that neomutt has a boolean variable called `crypt_confirmhook` which `If set, then you will be prompted for confirmation of keys when using the crypt-hook command. If unset, no such confirmation prompt will be presented. [...considered unsafe...].`     `crypt-hook` has the same "<pattern> <key>" args as `pgp-hook` and seems to supercede it.  Plain old mutt 1.6.0 that I'm running has the same `crypt_confirmhook` config command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [Dale Woolridge](http://www.woolridge.org/mutt/)'s [confirm-crypt-hook](http://www.woolridge.org/mutt/confirm-crypt-hook.html) patch has been merged into `mutt`.

1. use `crypt-hook` rather than `pgp-hook`.

`crypt-hook foo@bar.com 0x123456789ABCDE01`

2. set `crypt_confirmhook=no` for that recipient.  e.g.

`send-hook ~t foo@bar.com 'set crypt_confirmhook=no'`

This should work with `mutt` or `neomutt`.

Comment: Ah, this by itself actually did nothing. However, in combination with `pgp-hook foo@bar.com 0x123456789ABCDE01` it skipped both. I guess that's what the `Use keyID` prompt in your link refers to. Thank you.

Comment: I assumed that `pgp-hook` was an earlier, semi-obsoleted form of `crypt-hook` (it takes the same args).

Comment: I just did a bit more testing. It seems that `pgp-hook` and `crypt_confirmhook=no` are sufficient to skip the dialog. `crypt-hook` doesn't seem to be necessary.